# devcontainer, how to make X display work (mount graphics inside docker in visual studio code)

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

Normally I use this trick to make X work inside docker:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v $HOME/Videos:/videos -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY --name knl kdenlive
```

I tried doing the same on a devcontainer:

```
{
    "name": "example_dockerized_environment",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "extensions": [
        "ms-vscode.cpptools",
        "twxs.cmake",
        "eamodio.gitlens"
    ],
    "mounts": [ "source=../,target=/home/project", "source=/tmp/.X11-unix, target=/tmp/.X11-unix"],
    "containerEnv": {
        "DISPLAY": "unix:0"
    },
    "runArgs": ["--privileged"]
}
```

As you can see, I passed `unix$DISPLAY` and also mounted `X11-unix`

But I get

```
root@5e6a10efbea6:/workspaces/leuze_lidar_volume/sdk/quanergy_client-master# ./visualizer --host localhost
ERROR: In /build/vtk6-YpT4yb/vtk6-6.2.0+dfsg1/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 1466
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x2293740): bad X server connection. DISPLAY=Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I do `echo $DISPLAY` inside docker I see nothing. I tried doing

export `DISPLAY=unix:0` then I get

```
root@5e6a10efbea6:/workspaces/leuze_lidar_volume/sdk/quanergy_client-master# ./visualizer --host localhost
ERROR: In /build/vtk6-YpT4yb/vtk6-6.2.0+dfsg1/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 1466
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x281dcf0): bad X server connection. DISPLAY=unix:0. Aborting.


Aborted (core dumped)
```

I also see no `/tmp.x11-unix` inside the container:

```
root@5e6a10efbea6:/tmp# ls -la /tmp 
total 16
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 4096 Mar 18 03:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Mar 18 03:45 ..
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Mar 18 03:42 vscode-git-askpass-c2ca47727522d7940b4cce1d99fcc88d32ccfefc.sock
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Mar 18 03:47 vscode-git-ipc-f52b0dbfd870db22481ea656170b7615ea1e6497.sock
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Mar 18 03:45 vscode-ipc-032f3099-16ea-4f5d-8561-586571a4aea9.sock
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Mar 18 03:32 vscode-ipc-425af2fc-ddb1-4554-b93b-3a5bede4c52d.sock
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Mar 18 03:47 vscode-ipc-58739ccc-fb7d-4289-808e-21d31c703d1a.sock
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Mar 18 03:42 vscode-ipc-aa7aed50-92e4-4b2b-b17e-d70c1bba595e.sock
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2342 Mar 18 03:46 vscode-remote-containers-6a199ce05d20a43a350860289798f388414d648c.js
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Mar 18 03:46 vscode-remote-containers-ipc-6a199ce05d20a43a350860289798f388414d648c.sock
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Mar 18 03:46 vscode-ssh-auth-6a199ce05d20a43a350860289798f388414d648c.sock
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 18 03:46 vscode-typescript0
root@5e6a10efbea6:/tmp#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this works:

```
{
    "name": "my_docker_environment",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "extensions": [
        "ms-vscode.cpptools",
        "twxs.cmake",
        "eamodio.gitlens",
        "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
    ],
    "containerEnv": {
        "DISPLAY": "unix:0"
    },
    "mounts": [
        "source=/tmp/.X11-unix,target=/tmp/.X11-unix,type=bind,consistency=cached"
      ],
    "runArgs": ["--privileged"]
}
```

I don't recall if `"runArgs": ["--privileged"]`  is needed but I guess no

**You migth need to do**

```
xhost local:root
```

on a terminal on the host before launching your app

Comment: Works for me as of March 2021 without ```---priviliged```

Comment: worked for me with the newest VSCode version (1.82.2). The `--privileged` option isnt necessary

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid `xhost +`, it is possible to forward the .Xauthority with `.devcontainer.json` like:

```
{
  "image": "..."
  "runArgs": [
    "--net", "host",
    "-e", "DISPLAY=:0",
    "-e", "XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.Xauthority",
    "-v", "${localEnv:HOME}/.Xauthority:/tmp/.Xauthority"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tested on macOS, the only extra setting in `devcontainer.json` I used:

```
    "containerEnv": {
        "DISPLAY": "docker.for.mac.host.internal:0"
    },
```

on host machine `xhost +localhost` before running devcontainer

Answer (score 1):

There are many different solutions on how to make x11 forwarding work with vscode on the internet. Docker 23 enabled docker buildkit as standard, some GUI applications, including openCV do not work anymore with the settings mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/550#issuecomment-501293753).

Instead, on ubuntu 22.04, vscode 1.76.0 and Docker 23.0.1, the following minimal `.devcontainer.json` file enables GUIs including opencv for me:

```
{
    "containerEnv": {
        "DISPLAY": "${localEnv:DISPLAY}",
    },
    "remoteEnv": {
        "DOCKER_BUILDKIT": "0", 
    },
    "image": "YOUR_DOCKER_IMAGE",
    "runArgs": [
        "--volume=/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix",
    ]
}
```

Interesting reads:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1409
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/550#issuecomment-501293753

Comment: Great! This works for me. In my case it was `matplotlib`'s `plt.show()` getting stuck from the devcontainer while other GUIs worked from the same environment. Another detail: I didn't need to set `DOCKER_BUILDKIT`.